# Statistics (Multinomial, expected value)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

In a large lot of manufactured items, $10\%$ contain one defect and $5\%$ contain more than one defect. Ten items are randomly selected from this lot for sale, and repair costs total, $C=X_1 +3X_2$ , where $X_1$ denotes the number of items among the $10$ sold having exactly one defect and $X_2$ denote the number of $10$ sold having two or more defects.

$A)$    What is the expected value of repair costs?

$B)$    What is the variance of the repair costs?

So, originally I thought of this as just two separate binomial distributions; however, after talking with my study group we now think this is a multinomial distribution. So, I think this is now a Binomial Distribution with another conditional distribution. So maybe a hierarchical model?

I am thinking that the first distribution is $X_1$~Binomial(10,.1)

and that the second distribution is $X_2$|$X_1$~Binomial(10-x, .05)?

Comment: **Hint.** What is the expected value and variance of the repair costs of *one* item?  How would that scale up to ten items?

Comment: If my distributions are correct then the expectation of X$_1$ +3X$_2$ is just the expectation of each one because expectations work across linear operators

Comment: If I understand your claim correctly, that's right.  Now what about the variances?  Use $\sigma^2 = E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$.